# Joining two columns but keeping multiple instances in SQL

Tags: sql, left-join

I am using SQL 2008 and am having a problem.

I have 3 different tables and here is a sample of my code.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name Age
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
```

This returns something like this:

```
Name Age
tom   12
ben   23
ian   12
```

I have another query

```
SELECT Name
FROM Table3
```

This returns this:

```
ian   12 
ian   12
ian   12
```

I want to verify that if a name and age are in name from the first query and is in the second query Table3.name it will return something like this:

```
ian   12 
ian   12
ian   12
```

I have been trying Join and Union on these two columns but so far have been only been able to get it to return. Any suggestions?

```
ian   12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be able to be simplified (need to see your table structures and sample data), but given your queries, a subquery should work for you:

```
SELECT T3.Name, T3.Age
FROM Table3 T3
    JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT Name, Age
        FROM Table1
            LEFT JOIN Table2
                ON Table1.ID = Table2.ID
    ) T ON T3.Name = T.Name AND T3.Age = T.Age
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/888c4/2)

Answer (score 2):

First you pronounce your problem - you want to get all records for which combination of `Name` and `Age` exists in recordset of distinct `Name` and `Age` from join. Then you use power of declarative language and a little of [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to get your solution:

```
;with CTE as (
    select distinct Name, Age
    from Table1 as T1
        inner join Table2 as T2 on T2.ID = T1.ID
)
select *
from Table3 as T3
where exists (select * from CTE as C where C.Name = T3.Name and C.Age = T3.Age)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/464c2/1) to fiddle with query

Comment: Nicely outlined. However, an EXISTS subquery doesn't have to evaluate to a row set of unique values, and so you don't need the `DISTINCT` in this case. Nor do you need a CTE actually. I mean, it's not as if you needed to reference the thing multiple times, and, moreover, putting the complete subquery into the EXISTS predicate would actually improve readability, IMHO.

Comment: missed point about distinct, thank you. About CTE - while it's often overused, in this case I should say I like it, - for me queries with massive subqueries in exists could become less readable, although it could be completely subjective thing

Comment: Also I don't know which alias to put before Name and Age columns, because OP havn't provided a schema and I always warn people from use subqueries withoud alias, it could lead to hidden bugs

Comment: Well, if table aliases can be omitted in SELECT without issues, they can certainly be omitted in WHERE too, so you wouldn't need to worry about not knowing what table either of the columns was coming from. That said, I agree with you entirely that omitting table aliases when referencing columns in such queries (ones that involve more than one table) is really bad practice.

Comment: As for CTEs, I'm of the opinion that they generally improve readability in many (perhaps most) cases but not always. In particular, when I was reading a query and found an EXISTS predicate, I would naturally expect the actual logic to be present exactly there, so that I don't have to jump back to the definition of the row set referenced by the predicate to see what's going on. Again, I'm talking specifically about situations where the logic is used only once, namely in the EXISTS predicate. And this subquery is not a particularly large one either. But yes, all this is probably subjective.

Comment: Well in subquery I could refer to field from outer table while in CTE I cannot. So if, for example, somebody will drop column `Name` from `Table1` (or `Table2`, don't know where it is :) ) then subquery still will work, because there's `Name` column in `Table3`, but `Name = T3.Name` will mean `T3.Name = T3.Name`, and query will return incorrect results. While CTE will fail and that's good in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I understand the issue, but I think you are mixing too different things. The poor practice of omitting table aliases should not be fixed specifically with moving a subquery logic to a CTE. But well, whatever floats your boat, as they say. :)

Comment: Well, I want my query to work, and for me putting query into subselect without aliases is NO NO NO, It could be really dangerous :)